# Error: Library prettydiff.beautify.markdown does not exist on VScode

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, formatting

After installing pretty formatter extension and tried to format css file the below error display and removed all css code.

vscode Error: Library prettydiff.beautify.markdown does not exist.

Any solutions please?

Answer (score 0):

After some workaround I found a solution.
I installed the another extension 'Beautify css/sass/scss/less'
Now that error dissappeared.